# converting problems between doubles and strings in Newtonsoft.Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have updated my Newtonsoft.Json version from "8.0.3" to "9.0.1", 
After the change, I started to face some converting problems between doubles and strings.

Here's some code:

```
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }       
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var json = "{\"Key\": 'test', \"Value\": 210001.0}";
        var kv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValue>(json);
    }
```

In Newtonsoft.Json version "8.0.3" - the output of the class would be:
Key - "test"
Value - "210001" // No .0

In Newtonsoft.Json version "9.0.1" the output of the class would be
Key - "test"
Value - "210001.0"

This happens only when the value is 210001.0 - for 210001.1 it would not happen.
Now I understand that the new version solves this problem better, but I have lot's of external code that depends on the old version solution.
How can I achieve the old versions solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution which will definitely work is applying custom `JsonConverter` to the property, which will give you the control over how value is serialized/deserialized.

First step is creating a new `JsonConverter`, which is quite simple in implementation. I just invoke `ToString()` on the value, which can be either a `decimal` or `double`.

```
public sealed class FloatStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return reader.Value.ToString();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(double) || objectType == typeof(decimal);
    }
}
```

I made it so it can work with both values of `FloatParseHandling` and it will format the values as I presented in my previous, incorrect answer. You can of course tweak it to your liking, if you want it to ignore the `FloatParseHandling` but it will need type-checking to do it.

Just remember, that default value of `FloatParseHandling` is `FloatParseHandling.Double`, so it will work correctly without changing the serializer settings.

What you need to do next is mark the property with appropriate attribute so serializer will know to use it.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FloatStringConverter))]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

After this, `Value` will contain the correct representation of number from JSON.

Comment: I didn't want to implement this via a converter but I guess it's the best solution that was proposed until now. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @olegchernyakov, just as a precaution, I would suggest to slightly change the implementation of the converter and replace the body of `CanConvert` with `throw new NotSupportedException();`. Since `CanConvert` is not called when property is marked with attribute, only when converter is added to the collection `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`, it could create some issues, because `CanConvert` would receive a type of property, which in your case would be `string` and not the number type. Removing the body would ensure that this converter is only used with `JsonConverterAttribute`.

Answer (score 4):

This happens, because apparently authors of `Newtonsoft.Json` changed the default value of `JsonSerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling`. This changed the intermediate type used in string conversion from numbers. `0` is present at the end of string, because deserializer uses `Decimal` as the number type and when you try to run

```
210001.0M.ToString()
```

you get

```
210001.0
```

To revert to old handling which is `Double` for numbers, you have to specify it explicitly when deserializing, eg.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValue>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Double });
```

This causes the deserializer to execute it as

```
210001D.ToString()
```

which returns

```
210001
```

See [demo at dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V2nh9h).

Be aware that you might lose some precision when changing from `Decimal` to `Double`.

EDIT:
I have traced the problem to slightly changed implementation of `JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue`. In version [8.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/8.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L617), it used the number type as an intermediate one, so `FloatParseHandling` was used during deserialization from `float` to `string`. In version [9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/9.0.1/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L626), it no longer used the number type, it just took a substring of JSON and set it as the value.

To sum up, I'm not familiar enough with JSON.net to suggest any other option than `JsonConverter` from my other answer. Maybe someone more familiar with it could offer something else.

Comment: I skipped over the fact that code which relies on a number being formatted differently, but still correctly, is a bit of a smell. Unless it has some deeper meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this code runs successfully on the dotnetfiddle, when I copy it to a winform, they both(double\decimal) produce results with the `.0`. I'm using the Json.net 9.0.1 package and my project is using 4.5 framework. Can you please open a winform on your PC and check the result?

Comment: You are correct, it does not work when executed locally. Also, it seems that the whole deserialization is executed quite differently than I thought, which renders my answer incorrect - I'm sorry for that. If destination property is `string`, no conversion is made and whatever was passed in JSON as value is treated as string and used as value. I will post a solution but it would require more research and debugging to track down the source of the change you encountered.

Comment: @olegchernyakov, I have added some explanation to my answer. However, I'm not really sure how is it working on dotnetfiddle - without stepped debugging, I am not be able to trace it.